# testdriven.io: Dockerizing Celery and Flask -- Making it work with Google Cloud Run

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, celery

I am following this course which works well locally: https://testdriven.io/courses/flask-celery/docker/.

I am not trying to deploy the service to Google Cloud Run. The way that Google Cloud Run works, it seems to be deploying single containers and does not follow the instructions laid out in the docker-compose.yml file, such as launching the redis service and executing the entrypoint instructions.

I am looking for suggestions on how to deploy the full service to Google Cloud.

Locally, the docker compose file creates multiple containers: the flask app, the celery worker, the redis database, etc.

Followed this approach to deploy to Google Cloud Run:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/jobs/build-create-python

In that case, only one container is created.

Comment: Google recently added sidecars to Cloud Run. Adapt your deployment starting here: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-multi-container-deployments